# Controlling shared internet connection on LAN, (no switch, just a basic lan with a modem and PC with two network adapter)

Tags: networking, bandwidth, internet-sharing

I have shared my internet modem connection using a PC with two LAN adapters.
I want to control the access of shared internet on my LAN.

IP of the internet modem is ----------> 192.168.1.1

Shared internet PC adapter1 IP is -> 192.168.1.2

Shared internet PC adapter2 IP is -> 10.68.84.1

i want access on the computer------> 10.68.84.2

i want access on the computer------> 10.68.84.3

but want to restrict access on------> 10.68.84.4

Comment: First thing that pops into mind is ACLs. Not sure if it will be feasible though. What's the brand of your internet modem ?

Comment: its the most basic internet modem

Nokia siemens network
Device Info 

Board ID: 96338W2

Software Version ID: V89.2.01.01 
Firmware Version: 3.12L.BSNL_01.A2pB023k.d20k_rc2
Bootloader (CFE) Version: 1.0.37-12.1
Wireless Driver Version: 4.170.16.0.cpe2.1sd1

Comment: http://www.ninjaromeo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Nokia-Siemens-Networks-modem-BSNL-Photos-300x225.jpg this is the modem

Comment: This can be done - sort-of - with appropriate software, however as long as you have only 2 ports in your PC its going to be difficult to share - and someone with networking knowledge will be able to bypass whatever you do very easily.  You might want to confirm if your computer uses Linux, Windows and if this can be changed.  Linux is better at doing this kind of stuff then Windows, but has a steep learning curve.

Comment: Do you have any VLAN capable (ie managed) switches you can use ?  You can - in theory anyway - use a VLAN switch to seperate out your network and make it more secure.    Also, is there a requirement that the IP addresses stay the same ?  The "correct" way of doing this is to have different subnets for routed vs non-routed traffic.

Comment: i dont have any switches. is there any software approach ? i can use linux if any software solution available.. ip address is not a constraint but must remain in same class

Comment: i am using the windows server 2003 on the pc with two LAN adapters